# centering the text of an input[type=button]

Tags: css

I did a lot of research about centering, but in this particular case I didn't find a solution. How to center the text "Télécharger" horizontally inside the input[type=button]

```
<input style="width: 82px; height: 40px;" value="Télécharger" type="button">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/redwgcxz/3/

Comment: It is in center already.

Comment: Not horizontally

Comment: It is already centered but you can't see it because of your width.

Comment: @flamant yeah that's because of the `width:82px`. Text in button is always centered by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `width: 82px` and set it to `width: auto`, and `height: auto`. But you can remove the width and height property and just leave a padding.

The width of your button will depend on the content of the value.

You can add more or less padding to if you want.

#### Snippet:

```html
<input style="padding: 10px" value="Télécharger" type="button">
```

Comment: Thank you MarkBurns, it is the solution